# Programatically redirect to node/nid doesn't redirect to url alias

Tags: 8, redirection, path-aliases

From what I understand the module 'GlobalRedirect' has been merged into the 'Redirect' module. So the redirect module should also redirect links as node/nid to it's url alias. When creating redirects trough the interface this works perfectly. But if I programatically do a redirect to a node/nid page it isn't being redirected to it's url alias..
Not sure if this is bad coding on my part, or feature not implemented in the module.

```
  /* @file EventSubscriber.php */

  public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $baseUrl = $event->getRequest()->getBaseUrl();
    $attr = $event->getRequest()->attributes;
    if(null !== $attr && null !== $attr->get('node') && $attr->get('node')->get('type')->getString() == 'product_group' && 
    $attr->get('_controller') == '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeViewController::view') {
      $node = $attr->get('node');
      $references = $node->get('field_references');
      $values = $references->referencedEntities();
      if($values){
        $nid = $values[0]->id();
        $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($baseUrl. '/' . $language . '/node/' . $nid));
      }
  }

  static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onRequest'];
    return $events;
  }
```

I'm using this code to redirect a product group to it's first referenced entity node, which uses automated url structure generated by a pathauto pattern, but the url alias isn't being shown after the redirect, it shows node/nid. I've verified that the url alias on that page actually works, and even added a redirect from that specific node/nid to it's url alias trough the interface, but no luck.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this working as intended? Is there a cleaner/better way for me to redirect? Still quite new to Drupal 8..

Using:
Drupal 8.1.3 
Redirect 8.x-1.0-alpha1 
Pathauto 8.x-1.0-alpha3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [Url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x).

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $node->id()]);
new RedirectResponse($url->toString());
```

Comment: This did it, awesome thx!